# Ambiguous Column Name with Group By

Tags: sql-server-2012, group-by, ambiguous

I am having `Ambiguous Column Name "Item"` error for the query below. However, I already type in the desired form as parameters are at the beginning of columns.

```
        SELECT  
          [Country Code],
          Item, 
          [FE SSO], 
          [Newest Job Number],
          [Newest Transaction Date],
          Z.ConsignDate AS [ConsignDate],
        FROM DailyOnhand

        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT 
              [Job Number], 
              [Item],
              Min([Transaction Day]) AS ConsignDate
            FROM vwAllTxns
            GROUP BY [Job Number], [Item]) Z 
                  ON vwDailyOnhand_v2.[Newest Job Number] = Z.[Job Number] 
                     AND vwDailyOnhand_v2.[Item] = Z.[Item]
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: You probably have a item column in both tables,so specify it beforehand.Also the subquery is unnecessary ,you can use a MIN() OVER PARTITION BY.. with a simple JOIN

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix `item` in your `select` with the name/alias of the table it is sourced from.

```
SELECT  
      d.[Country Code],
      d.Item, 
      d.[FE SSO], 
      d.[Newest Job Number],
      d.[Newest Transaction Date],
      Z.ConsignDate AS [ConsignDate],
    FROM DailyOnHand d
      LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
          v.[Job Number], 
          v.[Item],
          Min(v.[Transaction Day]) AS ConsignDate
        FROM vwAllTxns v
        GROUP BY v.[Job Number], v.[Item]
        ) Z 
              ON d.[Newest Job Number] = Z.[Job Number] 
                 AND d.[Item] = Z.[Item]
```

Your `from` specifies `DailyOnHand` but your `on` specifies `vwDailyOnhand_v2`, I removed the later and used an alias instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT  
      [Country Code],
      Z.[Item], -- Need to specify which item is source 
      [FE SSO], 
      [Newest Job Number],
      [Newest Transaction Date],
      Z.ConsignDate AS [ConsignDate],
    FROM DailyOnhand

    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
          [Job Number], 
          [Item],
          Min([Transaction Day]) AS ConsignDate
        FROM vwAllTxns
        GROUP BY [Job Number], [Item]) Z 
              ON vwDailyOnhand_v2.[Newest Job Number] = Z.[Job Number] 
                 AND vwDailyOnhand_v2.[Item] = Z.[Item]
```